# Using breeze in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, breeze, apache-spark-ml

I want to use breeze in spark to perform some calculations and ultimately implement an R package for spark https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36727811/spark-weighted-repeated-median-smoothing-and-filtering

However, I encountered a problem getting started with breeze. If combined with spark the breeze implicits do not seem to be imported properly

```
import breeze.linalg.{ DenseVector => BDV }
import breeze.stats.distributions.Poisson
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.{ SparkConf, SparkContext}
import breeze.stats.{ mean => bmean}

import breeze.stats._

class RobfilterR extends App {

  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("RobfilterR").setMaster("local[*]")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  val sql = new SQLContext(sc)

  val poi = Poisson(3.0)
  val x = poi.sample(10)
  val v = BDV(x.toArray)
  bmean(v)
```

}

But basic breeze functions do not work anymore because the implicits were not imported correctly. What is wrong here?

```
error: could not find implicit value for parameter impl: breeze.stats.mean.Impl[breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Int],VR]
              bmean(v)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The source of the problem is an argument you pass to `mean` not imports.
Breeze simply doesn't implement mean for `Vector[Int]`.

```
import breeze.stats.mean
import breeze.linalg.{Vector, DenseVector}

val v = DenseVector(1, 2, 3)
mean(v)
// error: could not find implicit value for parameter impl:  
//   breeze.stats.mean.Impl[breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Int],VR]
//     mean(v)
```

If you want to compute mean you'll have to cast it to a supported type first:

```
import breeze.linalg.convert

mean(convert(v, Double))
// Double = 2.0
```